# Most general exponential $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I am familiar with the multivalued general definition of exponentiation, namely,
$$z^w = \exp(w\log z) = \exp(w(\log|z|+i\arg(z))).$$
My question is, what is the most general definition for $x^y$ as a map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$? I think it is this:
$$x^y=\begin{cases}
\exp(y\log x) & \text{if $x>0$}\\[5pt]
\hfil 0 \hfil & \text{if $x=0$ and $y\geqslant0$}\\[5pt]
\hfil\sqrt[b]{x^a}\hfil & \text{if $x<0$ and $y=\frac ab$ with $b$ odd}.
\end{cases}$$
In other words, for positive bases we define it as usual with the real logarithm (or as $\lim x^{y_n}$ where $y_n$ is a sequence of rational numbers converging to $y$, such as its decimal expansion). For negative bases, we can only define it for rational powers with odd denominators in reduced form, since these are the only powers which give a real root ($r^b = x^a$ only has real roots $r$ for odd values of $b$).

Is this the most general definition we can have? It seems strange that we can make sense of $x^{1.4}$ for all real $x$, but not of $x^{1.5}$.

Comment: The fact that you find strange boils down to the fact that $x^n$ cannot be negative if $n$ is even. What's so strange about that?

Comment: @RobArthan I'm just asking for verification of what I _think_ is the most general definition possible.

Comment: If $x=0$ and $y=0$ then $x^y$ is definitely not $0$. It's much more useful define it as $1$ and some people prefer to left it undefined, but it's never defined as $0$

Answer (score 1):

You need to be very careful when you are trying to define $x^{a/b}$ with $x<0$. You defined it as $\sqrt[b]{x^a}$ which is equivalent to $(x^a)^{1/b}$, but why?

Probably because you are thinking that $(x^a)^{1/b} = x ^{a \cdot (1/b)} = x^{a/b}$, but you are using the exponent rule $(x^r)^s = x ^{ rs}$ which is NOT valid for $x<0$.

That's why often $x^{a/b}$ is not defined in a general way, because it's not possible to define it in such a way that the exponent rules are valid.